# Bounding the $n$-th term of a sequence, given a non-linear recursive bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrences

I asked the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136248/bounding-the-nth-term-of-a-sequence-given-a-recursive-non-linear-bound) question in MSE:

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+$.
> Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a sequence satisfying
> $$|x_n|\leq a|x_{n-1}|+b|x_{n-1}|^2, $$
> for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How can we bound $|x_n|$ with a number $M_n$ depending on $n$, $a$, $b$, and $x_0$?

However, I did not get an answer.
It seems that there should be some obvious observation to give a naive upper bound? Although it would be nice to have an asymptotically tight bound in closed form, if possible of course!

Comment: Would you be able to solve it if $a=0$? (Hint: The sequence $y_n = \log \lvert x_n \vert$ may be easier to handle.) If yes, could you round up the first term so that you could combine it with the second term?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen how do you do the round up?

Comment: Well, for example, suppose $\lvert x_{n-1} \rvert \ge 1$. Then $a \lvert x_{n-1} \rvert + b \lvert x_{n-1} \rvert^2 \le (a+b) \lvert x_{n-1} \rvert^2$ so now your RHS is much simpler, although more loose. You can vary this theme by assuming different things about $x_{n-1}$. If you want you can break into cases, and in each case you can try to make your inequality as tight as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define the sequence $y_n$ by $y_0=|x_0|$, $y_{n+1}=ay_n+by_n^2$. Then we have
$|x_n|\leq y_n$ for all $n$, since $ay+by^2$ is increasing for positive $a,b$,
and it is enough to estimate the positive sequence $y_n$. Setting $z_n=by_n$, we obtain a simpler recurrent relation
$z_{n+1}=az_n+z_n^2.$ For this last relation, the behavior depends on $a$. If $a\geq 1$, all orbits tend to $+\infty$ and $z_n\sim \exp(2^nu(a,z_0))$ where $u$ is a positive
function. If $a<1$, then there is a positive fixed point $z^*=1-a$. When $z_0>z^*$
the behavior is as above, when $z_0<z^*$, the orbit tends to $0$ as the geometric
progression: $z_n\sim a^n$, and when $z_0=z^*$ then $z_n=z^*$.

For the function $u(a,z)$, there is no explicit expression, it is variously known as
the Green function of the complement of the Julia set, or the equilibrium potential of the Julia set. This function is actually easy to compute by the formula
$$u(a,z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{-n}\log|f^n(z)|,$$
where $f^n$ is the $n$-th iteration of the function $f^1(z)=az+z^2.$ This expression converges very fast.

Ref:
Douady, A.; Hubbard, J. H.
Étude dynamique des polynômes complexes. Partie I.
Publications Mathématiques d'Orsay, 84-2. Université de Paris-Sud, Département de Mathématiques, Orsay, 1984. 75 pp.
[available online](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/PMO/feuilleter.php?id=PMO_1984)

Comment: First things first, thank you for the answer. If you could also you please copy your answer to the linked MSE because I offered a bounty for it. Second, is there a detailed reference for the behavior of such sequences where the constants are all computed explicitly?

Comment: In particular,  I would like to compute explicitely the constant $C$ for which $z_n\leq e^{2^nu(a,z_0)}$ and the fixed point $z^*$.

Comment: I meant $z_n\leq Ce^{2^nu(a,z_0)}$ in the previous comment

Comment: I did not say that there is a constant $C$. I only mean that $z_n=\exp(2^nu(a,z_0)+o(2^n))$ when $z_0>z^*$.

Comment: In the case when $a\geq 1$, which is the case I'm interested in, we get that $z_n=e^{2^nu(a,z_0)+o(2^n)}$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, We have this in both cases, unqualified (since $u(a,z_0)=0$ when $a\in[0,1]$ and $z<z^*$). But in the case $a<1$ and $z<z^*$ we have additional, more precise information.

Comment: I have asked another similar question on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144417/asymptotic-behavior-of-the-quadratic-recurrence-x-n-x-n-12c. It would be great if could help out again!

Comment: @UserA: this is the same question and I think I answered it.